# Javascript - Repeat a character a number of times based on a string character length

Tags: javascript

How can I repeat a letter or character for example "A" an X amount of times based on a string length number in Javascript? For example, user inputs the word "Outrageous" which has 10 letters and I want to output a * for each letter counted on from the input.

I tried this:

document.write("Your password " + **str.replace(password.length),"*")** + "has been accepted");

but it doesn't work

Comment: ` str.replace(/./g,'*')`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```js
let password = "abcd";

let res = "x".repeat(password.length)

console.log(res)
```